# equality with 3 equaties

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have ended up with an equation looking like this:

a+2b = c+b = 2c+a

a+b+c = 1

I have not tried working with 3 equating before, so I am a little lost. And ofc I want to solve the equation above. Normally if we had such an equation:

a+2b = 4b

a+b = 1

then we can just isolate ei. a by using the same operation on both sides.
What if we have 3 equaties?

Thanks

Comment: $a+2b=2c+a$ tells you ... what? Then using that information in $a+2b= c+b$ tells you ... what? Then $a+b+c=1$ tells you ... what?

Comment: Are you still there? Have you made any progress? Have you tried to follow my reasoning?

Comment: Question evidently abandoned by author.

Comment: That wasn't very necessary though....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned (or hinted rather) in the comments, substitution can be used to solve the equalities.

Regarding your confusion on the case having 3 equalities, this can be further broken down into 3 separate equalities containing 2 terms each. In this case, they would be:

$$\begin{cases}
a+2b = c+b \\
a+2b = 2c+a \\
c+b = 2c+a \\
\end{cases}$$

Then these equations can be substituted separately into the equation $a+b+c = 1$

You will get the solution set of $(a, b, c) = (0, 1/2, 1/2)$.